# Try to export Iot Services .json Data to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub

When I export .json data from Azure IoT services to Blob storage , the blob storage save the source files without extension instead of .json .  Is there a way to fix that? I am Following this way because I am going to conect Power BI on that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The extension of the file is not shown in the blob when uploaded using data export from IoT Central app because the exported files contain a single line per record and the extension of the file is not included in the exported data.

Since the data export process in IoT Central app is designed to export data in a specific format, such as JSON or CSV. These formats do not typically require file extensions to be included in the filename.

When data is exported from IoT Central, it is saved as a file with a unique filename such as the device ID or data type.

I created Iot Central app and configured with the storage account and exported data using data export.

[image]

In this case, the ".json" extension is not necessary to identify the file format because it is implied by the export process. Similarly, if the data was exported in CSV format, the filename might be "20210308-Device1234-TelemetryData.csv", and the ".csv" extension would be implied.

The exported data has the id of the device template, display name of the device template, device capability model, cloud properties definitions, and overrides and initial values.

[image]

[image]

For further information refer to [Export-to-blob-storage.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-central/core/howto-export-to-blob-storage.md)